# CGO: converting Go byte array into C char* and back, issue with null terminator in byte array

Tags: go, memory, c-strings, cgo

Brief Context:
I am trying to create a cgo cache from uint64->[]byte for my company. Golang's `map[uint64][]byte` incur considerable latency due to the garbage collector as []byte is considered a pointer. As such, I would like to try to use CGO to avoid the issue. I am currently implementing a `C++ unordered_map<unsigned long long, char*>` to handle that. I managed to get the C++ wrappers to work but I am facing a major issue.

Currently, I am converting my Go byte array using

```
b := []byte{1,0,3,32,2,2,2,2}
str := C.String(b)
bb := []byte(C.GoString(str))
```

However, it turns out my my bb is `[]byte{1}`. The 0 in the byte array is seen as the `'/0'` and thus shorten the string. Furthermore, it seems to have cause out of memory issue when I delete entries with

`delete (map->find(key))->second`. I suspect this is because that chars after the first `'/0'` does not get deallocated.
I am not sure how else to do this. Personally, I am new to CGO so I never used it prior to this project so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

- Use `C.CBytes`, not `C.CString`.

  Please read [this](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) in its entirety before using `cgo`.
- The `C.C*` functions which allocate (`C.CString` and `C.CBytes` do that) internally call `malloc()` from the linked in `libc` library to get the destination memory block, and you're supposed to eventually call `C.Free()` on them (which calls `libc`'s `free()`), as documented.

  AFAIK, C++ compiler is by no means oblidged to use `libc`'s `malloc()` and `free()` to implement `new` and `delete`, so calling `delete` on the results of `C.C*` functions is a sure path to disaster.

  The simplest way to solve this, IMO, is to export a "constructor" function from your C++ side: something like

  ```cpp
  extern "C" {
      char* clone(char *src, size_t len);
  }
  ```

  …which would 1) allocate a memory block of length `len` using whatever method works best for C++; 2) copy `len` bytes from `src` to it; 3) return it.

  You could then call it from the Go side—as `C.clone(&b[0], len(b))` and call it a day: the C++ side is free to call `delete` on the result.

Comment: You're correct that C++ `new` does not *have* to call `malloc`. I haven't seen any that don't (as a default anyway), and a quick search suggests that at least most of them do, but it's probably wisest to do as you suggested here.